# Having trouble writting a query with "case" in sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

In the query below, I keep getting the error "An expression of non boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected near End". Down below is my code I'm not trying to return the rows where the pk__street_name == NULL in the join. But I get the error listed above. How can I fix this.

```py
result = session.query(
   tamDnRangeMap, tamStreet
 ).join(tamStreet)
  .filter(
     case(
         [(tamDnRangeMap.pk_street_name == NULL, 0)],
         else_ = 1
     )
 ).all()
```

Comment: This `case` expression gives you 1 or 0 integer value, so your `filter` expression would look something like that `filter(0)` and sqlalchemy does not allow it. What would you like to filter?

Answer (score 1):

First remark is that you don't want equality comparisons anywhere near `NULL` in SQL, it is done with `IS` or `IS NOT`.

Once you know that, you can use SQLAlchemy's [`is_`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.is_) or [`isnot`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.isnot)* operators.

All in all, you're using `CASE` where you don't really need it, put the `IS NOT NULL` condition in filter directly.

```py
result = (
    session.query(tamDnRangeMap, tamStreet)
    .join(tamStreet)
    .filter(tamDnRangeMap.pk_street_name.isnot(None))
    .all()
)
```

---

* **NB.** [`isnot`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.isnot) has been deprecated and is replaced by [`is_not`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.is_not) since SQLAlchemy 1.4, but the question uses [`case with list of whens`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=case#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) which was also deprecated in 1.4.